# What is $\operatorname{Ass}\operatorname{Ext}^i(M,N)$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian

This is exercise 1.2.27 of Bruns-Herzog:
Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $M$ a finite $R$-module and $N$ an arbitrary $R$-module. Deduce that $\operatorname{Ass}(\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)) = \operatorname{Ass}N \cap \operatorname{Supp}M$. (*answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417703/asociated-prime-ideals-of-hom-bruns-and-herzog-exercise-1-2-27)* )

> I want to know if there is a similar expression for $\operatorname{Ass}\operatorname{Ext}^i(M,N)$ (with extra assumptions if needed)? Specially I want to know $\operatorname{Ass}\operatorname{Ext}^i(R/I,N)$, when $R$ is local.

I know that $\operatorname{Ass}\operatorname{Ext}^i(R/I,N) \subseteq \operatorname{supp}\operatorname{Ext}^i(R/I,N) \subseteq \operatorname{supp}N \cap \operatorname{supp}R/I$, but is there a kind of equality?

Comment: Duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32137/the-associated-prime-ideals-of-exti-rm-n\ related to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/89747/relation-between-ass-extm-n-and-ass-m-ass-n

Comment: yes but this is a bit different.

Comment: Well, first of all, when $R$ is local those Ext modules will be zero for $i < \operatorname{depth}_I N$. I think those answers linked by @user26857 are related to your question. Can you explain what you mean by a bit different?

Comment: "with extra assumptions if needed" e.g "R/I or R/m as M"

Comment: If $M$ is $R/m$, then the support of $M$ is $\{ m \}$. Maybe it'd be nice if you can come up with some examples showing equalities in your question may happen. Or you can ask for examples where the inclusions are strict.

Comment: equal to what? I dont have any idea. maybe there is equality; but not to  AssN∩SuppM